# How to plot 3D maximum and minimum surfaces?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I want to plot the maximum and minimum 3D surface for the following property:

```
Property[θ, ϕ, χ] := Module[{a, b},
  a = dirVector[θ, ϕ];
  b = dirVector2[θ, ϕ, χ]];
```

The following is a 2 parameter version of what I want:

```
SphericalPlot3D[Property[θ, ϕ], θ, ϕ, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: What is `dirVector`?

Comment: They are direction vectors:

Comment: Defining Euler angles

Comment: What is the code for `dirVector` and `dirVector2`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: dirVector[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := {Sin[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Phi]], 
   Sin[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Phi]], Cos[\[Theta]]};

Comment: dirVector2[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, \[Chi]_] := {Cos[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Phi]]*
     Cos[\[Chi]] - Sin[\[Phi]]*Sin[\[Chi]],
   Cos[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Phi]]*Cos[\[Chi]] + 
    Cos[\[Phi]]*Sin[\[Chi]], -Sin[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Chi]]};

Comment: @John: Please put that into your question. Please also fix the function name, since `Property` is a protected symbol in *Mathematica*.

Comment: What is a *maximum* surface?  What is a 3D surface, a hypersurface in 4-space (a 1-dimensional higher analog of your 2-parameter version), or a 2D surface in 3-space?

Comment: @MichaelE2: It is also highly unclear to me, what the `Module` might be all about, or the `SphericalPlot3D` without ranges.

Comment: @Jinxed The code is unilluminating to me, too.

Answer (score 3):

I am unsure what you are after, but I'll give it a try:

Given your vectors

```
dirVector[θ_, ϕ_] := {Sin[θ]*Cos[ϕ], Sin[θ]*Sin[ϕ], Cos[θ]};
dirVector2[θ_, ϕ_, χ_] := {Cos[θ]*Cos[ϕ]*Cos[χ]-Sin[ϕ]*Sin[χ], 
                           Cos[θ]*Sin[ϕ]*Cos[χ]+Cos[ϕ]*Sin[χ],
                           -Sin[θ]*Cos[χ]};
```

only the second one has, when `χ` is varied, a minimum and maximum surface, with the minimum "surface" degenerating to a line at `π/2`, the maximum being the full sphere at `0` and `π`, respectively.

I plotted this with `dirVector` slightly scaled down so as to see the effects:

[image: animated display]

The plot was created using `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
Animate[Column[{"χ=" <> ToString@N@χ, 
   ParametricPlot3D[{.9 dirVector[θ, ϕ], 
     dirVector2[θ, ϕ, χ]}, {θ, 0, 
     2 π}, {ϕ, 0, π}, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Mesh -> None, 
    ImageSize -> Medium]}, Alignment -> Center], {χ, 
  0, π, π/64}]
```